# Display list results layout

Tags: xamarin

Hi every one this code display a list with Name,issue,age,location
I am just wondering how to display it instead displaying it like this:
Name | issue |age |location

How would I display it like this:

Name             Issue

Age               Location

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Issue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtIssue"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Age"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtAge"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtLocation"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You need a Vertical Layout, with two nested Horizontal ones.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="50">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtIssue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="Issue" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="50">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtAge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:text="Age" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:text="Location" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```